# What is the mechanism for tf.data.dataset.shuffle?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tfrecord

Say I have 100,000 examples in one tfrecord. I do a shuffle with buffer size 100, will it shuffle every 100 examples, after we consume all the examples and draw another 100 examples into shuffle. Or while we consume the training data, it will fill in later examples as well and draw uniformly from the shuffle, such that at some point of time, every example has some probability that it is in the buffer?

It think the latter makes more sense. Is it how the shuffle function implemented? I looked up but found source of explaining the mechanism.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets)

> The `Dataset.shuffle()`transformation randomly shuffles the input
>   dataset using a similar algorithm to tf.RandomShuffleQueue: it
>   maintains a fixed-size buffer and chooses the next element uniformly
>   at random from that buffer.

You can find the definition of the operation [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.10/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py), and that directs to the [`ShuffleDataset`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/83f1458ec1c19b3d46676ab543dff4ec401a0dd0/tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc).

Additionally, note that the shuffle operation also allows you to determine *how* the batch is drawn (i.e., whether, after one epoch, the dataset is pseudo-randomly shuffled in total).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I kept a 1500 size of buffer, where each example is of shape 10x128x128x3, batch size is about 30, the process of filling up shuffle can be pretty slow I guess. However, when I look at the log, since the inference is fast, I saw lots of logging info says filling up the shuffle. from 0 to 1500, periodically. That makes me wonder whether it actually keep a fixed size shuffle. Should I use the prefetch as well? Since if the shuffle kept a fixed buffer, why do we need prefetch?

Comment: Actually, even if I added prefetch, I still have the logging info once for a while that indicates filling of the shuffle buffer, which is strange because I thought it will automatically fetch next examples into the buffer. Does this happen when the consumption is significantly faster than pushing into shuffle?